# Dynamically how to set value to selected of select dropdown in angularjs depending upon value stored in array of objects

Tags: angularjs

```
I have multiple records which are stored in
```

$scope.myQuality

variable currently in in below attached plnkr but that data will be coming from rest api. Currently i have used ng-options for display select options which i am getting from $scope.items. Depending upon the value of ("status": true) i want to make the dropdown value selected to "OK"

If

("status": true)

-> selected value in dropdown should be OK

If

("status": false)

-> selected value in dropdown should be KO

If

> ("status": null)

-> selected value in dropdown should be empty

Each record will have dropdown but it's selected value will differ depending on the value of status within

> $scope.myQuality

Please find the below url

http://plnkr.co/edit/aW5enrHuEZ2jHiQuHQmV?p=preview

> Id
>                                           
>                                           
>                                       
>                                   
>                                   
>                                       Date
>                                           
>                                           
>                                       
>                                   
>                                   Status
>                               
>                           
>                           
>                                 
>                                     {{ roll. id}}
>                                     {{ roll. date | date:"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" }}

script.js

> // Code goes here
>
> angular.module('sortApp', [])
>
> .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
>       $scope.sortType     = 'id'; // set the default sort type
>       $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
>       $scope.searchLists   = '';     // set the default search/filter term
>
> ```
> $scope.items =[
>     {"value":true,"text":"OK"},
>     {"value":false,"text":"KO"}
> ];
>
>    $scope.myQuality = [
>   {
>             "id": 1,
>             "status": true,
>             "date": 1474864500000,
>   }, {
>             "id": 2,
>             "status": false,
>             "date": 1474741800000,
>   },{
>             "id": 3,
>             "status": null,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   },{
>             "id": 4,
>             "status": true,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   },{
>             "id": 5,  
>              "status": true,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   },{
>             "id": 6,  
>              "status": true,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   },{
>             "id": 7,  
>             "status": true,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   },{
>             "id": 8,  
>              "status": true,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   },{
>             "id": 9,  
>             "status": true,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   },{
>             "id": 10,  
>             "status": false,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   },{
>             "id": 11,  
>              "status": true,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   },{
>             "id": 12,  
>             "status": false,
>             "date": 1474914600000,
>   }   ] });
> ```

Comment: have updated the plnkr url.

Comment: @jinishshah it's better to include the code in your post than to link to it from a third party site. eventually, your plunkr link will break, making this post useless to future users having similar problems.

Comment: @TheHeadRush have included the code. if anything more is required please let me know. also share how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the track by from your ng-options, plnkr below:

https://plnkr.co/edit/olbqvp2GiTTqr1JUyeSq?p=preview

```
ng-options="option.value as option.text for option in items"
```

Comment: Excellent. I was trying to understand, but I believe the track by is correct. Thanks!

Comment: If you need the null option also, you can put in items the value:         {"value":null,"text":""}

Comment: @gustavo gabriel - But the options value attribute is now set to boolean:true & boolean:false. I want it to be set to true & false only.

Comment: @jinishshah I dont know what you mean by options value, they are working as true and false..

Comment: @GustavoGabriel i mean by the option value <option label="OK" value="boolean:true" selected="selected">OK</option> instead it should appear as <option label="OK" value="true" selected="selected">OK</option>. since depending on that value i have to do some task & open popup